# Can JavaFX Webview send a notification?

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I'm pretty new to using JavaFX and Webview. What I want to do is when the address of the webengine (i assume this is accessed through webengine.getLocation()) changes to a specific web address to fire an event, ie play a sound file. I'm a little lost on where to start with this though. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*General Approach*

If you only want to play a ping! on navigation to a specific location (e.g. every time somebody goes to somewhere starting with 'http://www.google.com'), write the [WebEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) location change listener to play an [AudioClip](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/AudioClip.html) like this:

```
final AudioClip ping = new AudioClip(
  "http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1815&type=wav"
);

webView.getEngine().locationProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
  @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldLocation, String newLocation) {
    if (newLocation != null && newLocation.startsWith("http://www.google.com") {
      ping.play();
    } 
  }
});
```

In general, for this kind of thing a format like an uncompressed wav is preferred for the audio clip as the ping is likely pretty small anyway and a wav file will play on all JavaFX target platforms without requiring an additional audio codec library to be installed.

*Sample Application*

Here is a mini-web browser sample application using `WebView` which going ping!

1. A ping! sounds every time a new page is loaded.
2. An anchor navigation on the same page doesn't count as a new page.
3. The ping sound used in the application is public domain and downloadable from: http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1815&type=wav
4. You should download and use a local version of the ping! sound if you want to use it in a real application.

Just enter the address you want to go to into the location text field, hit enter, and hear it go ping as it loads up the page.

*TheMachineThatGoesPing.java*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.media.AudioClip;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TheMachineThatGoesPing extends Application {
  private static final String HOME_LOC = 
    "http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Monty_Python's_The_Meaning_of_Life";

  private WebView   webView;
  private AudioClip ping;

  public static void main(String[] args) { Application.launch(TheMachineThatGoesPing.class); }

  @Override
  public void init() throws Exception {
    ping = new AudioClip("http://soundbible.com/grab.php?id=1815&type=wav");
  }

  @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    webView = new WebView();
    webView.setPrefWidth(1000);

    final TextField location = new TextField();
    location.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        if (!location.getText().startsWith("http")) {
          location.setText("http://" + location.getText());
        }
        webView.getEngine().load(location.getText());
      }
    });

    webView.getEngine().locationProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
      @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldLocation, String newLocation) {
        location.setText(newLocation);
        ping.play();
      }
    });

    webView.getEngine().load(HOME_LOC);

    VBox layout = new VBox(10);
    layout.setStyle("-fx-padding: 10; -fx-background-color: cornsilk;");
    layout.getChildren().setAll(
      location,
      webView
    );

    stage.setTitle("The machine that goes 'ping!'");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
    stage.show();
  }
}
```